# Calling Fortran DLL in C# with String arguments

Tags: c#, string, dll, parameters, fortran

I am trying to pass a string variable from c# to fortran dll.

My C# code;

```
namespace fortrandll
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport(@"csbdll10.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "sub")]
        public static extern void sub(ref StringBuilder dbname, ref int n);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {          
            StringBuilder dbname = new StringBuilder(5);
            dbname.Append("dbname");
            int n = 5;                           
            sub(ref dbname, ref n);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Fortran code;

```
subroutine sub(dbname,leng) bind(C,name="sub")
    use iso_c_binding
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES reference :: dbname
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES VALUE :: len
  implicit none
  integer, intent(in)::leng
  character, intent(in):: dbname(leng)
  write(*,*) dbname
  return
end
```

Both the programs are compiled successfully.

But when I run the C# code getting some ascii code as result of fortran call rather intended output.

When I tried without ref keyword in C# getting Access Violation Exception.

Other things tried are Unmanaged datatypes and char bytes.

Thanks for the help.

Update: After removing 'ref' keyword for Stringbuilding and in functional call, getting the expected output.

Update Code:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport(@"csbdll10.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "sub")]
    public static extern void sub(StringBuilder dbname, ref int n);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {          
        StringBuilder dbname = new StringBuilder();
        dbname.Append("dbname name is here");
        int n = dbname.Length;                           
        sub(dbname, ref n);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"But when I run the C# code getting some ascii code as result of fortran call rather intended output."_ Can you add what you get and what you expect? My first guess would be that you are passinga ref to a `StringBuilder`not a `string` which is not the same.

Comment: I am passing "dbname" string to the fortran, but I get some non-readable ASCII values. StringBuilder is used in passing arguments rather C# strings directly.

Comment: Try passing a string.  What code are you getting?  The return value is a byte[] terminated with a '\0'. The length must include the termination which is one longer than what you expect.

Comment: _"I am passing "dbname" string to the fortran"_ - No, you actually do not. You are passing a reference to a `StringBuilder`. That is an important distinction as soon as you are going full P/Invoke.

Comment: Yes,  @Fildor - I removed the ref to stringbuilder and getting the expected output. Thank you very much!